# SM Session Authentication issue from Site Minder getting HTML Login Page

Tags: java, jboss, session-cookies, jboss7.x, siteminder

We are getting HTML login page while hitting Site Minder service using SM Session in Java service.

The service is hosted in JBOSS server. Could you please let us know if we can handle this issue in JBOSS server through any configuration

NOTE : We are getting cookie from httprequest by using httprequest.getcookie().Tried to flush out the cookie by using maxagelimit but it didn't worked.